# Como exibir dados php/mysql e AngularJs?

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs

Estou tentando fazer uns testes com PHP + MySQL + AngularJS e fiquei parada em uma duvida de como tratar os dados do banco com angular e mandar para tela, tenho os seguintes códigos:

**con-bd.php**

```
<?php
....

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $base) or die(mysqli_error());

$query = "SELECT matricula, nome FROM sca_pessoa" or die(mysqli_error());

$result = $conn->query($query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $json_str = json_encode($row)   
    echo $json_str;
}

# retorna json assim, meio errado?
/*
{"0":"182354X","matricula":"182354X","1":"RAFAEL CAMPOS PIMENTEL","nome":"RAFAEL CAMPOS PIMENTEL"}
{"0":"1823558","matricula":"1823558","1":"RAQUEL CARVALHO SANTANA","nome":"RAQUEL CARVALHO SANTANA"}
{"0":"182371X","matricula":"182371X","1":"JULIANA PINHEIRO GOMES","nome":"JULIANA PINHEIRO GOMES"}
*/
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("pessoasCtrl", function($scope) {

});
```

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App com PHP e AngularJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="pessoasCtrl">
        <h3>App PHP + AngularJS</h3>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Então, estou meio tentando saber como vou fazer isso exatamente.

Answer (score 3):

**Formato JSON**
Me parece que você está querendo passar uma coleção, mas está retornando 3 objetos. O formato ideal seria assim:

```
[
{"0":"182354X","matricula":"182354X","1":"RAFAEL CAMPOS PIMENTEL","nome":"RAFAEL CAMPOS PIMENTEL"},
{"0":"1823558","matricula":"1823558","1":"RAQUEL CARVALHO SANTANA","nome":"RAQUEL CARVALHO SANTANA"},
{"0":"182371X","matricula":"182371X","1":"JULIANA PINHEIRO GOMES","nome":"JULIANA PINHEIRO GOMES"}
]
```

Perceba os colchetes (que determinam o início e fim de uma coleção) e as vírgulas (separando os objetos individualmente).

**Interpretando JSON**

Você pode utilizar o serviço `$http` para carregar e interpretar o conteúdo vindo do banco:

```
$http.get('con-bd.php').success(function(response) {
    return response.data;
});
```

Comment: entendo,  mas a questão é que esse json está saindo errado. =\

Comment: @phpricardo Seria o caso então de você ajustar `con-db.php` para incluir os colchetes (no início e fim) e vírgulas (para todas as linhas exceto a última).

Comment: Mas porque esse json que sai do jeito que sai, está com duplicidade no número de matrícula e nome? Isso que estou achando estranho. Vi uns códigos que podem criar uma formatação mesmo, mas penso que poderia ter isso já pronto (função php).

Answer (score 3):

Isso é devido ao array que é retornado da função do MySQL `mysqli_fetch_array`. Neste array,  ele mapeia o valor da coluna pelo índice e pelo nome da coluna, por isso você ve o mesmo valor mapeado tanto pra `0` quanto pra `matricula`.

O ideal é você mapear esse resultado para um outro array, como você desejar. Por exemplo:

```
$response = array();

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $json["matricula"] = $row[0];
     $json["nome"] = $row[1];
     array_push($response, $json);  
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

O interessante seria mapear isso para uma classe `Aluno` e transformar essa classe em JSON.

Comment: Deu mais ou menos certo Paulo, mas a questão é que ainda continua duplicando e ele ainda cria [{ ... }] para cada dado.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Veja se funciona assim.

Answer (score 2):

Passei por uma situação semelhante esses dias, no meu caso eu joguei o resultado para um outro array para depois codificar para json. No exemplo que se segue é um trecho do meu código que usei, neste caso minha conexão é PDO e estou retorando como Objeto, já para adiantar as coisas, análise o exemplo acredito que possa te ajudar:

```
$smtt_select = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM contatos');
$smtt_select->execute();

$res = [];

while($resultado = $smtt_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    array_push($res, $resultado);
}

$json = json_encode($res);

echo $json;
```

Comment: Adaptei o meu code para pdo tb e fiz como vc fez, mas nenhum resultado =( sacanagem isso. Só o meu que não funciona. http://pastebin.com/ucjmXzJ3

Comment: No seu código você está usando  
   while($row = $smt_select->fetch() tente usar "fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)" como eu fiz.

Answer (score 1):

app.js
//cria o server

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.factory("services", ['$http', function($http) {
  var serviceBase = 'services/'
    var obj = {};
    //busca os dados do cliente
    obj.getPessoas = function(){
        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'pessoas');
    }
    return obj;   
}]);
//cria a controller
app.controller('lista', function ($scope, services) {
    services.getPessoas().then(function(data){
        $scope.pessoas = data.data;
    });
});
//Cria as rotas
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        title: 'Exemplo Angular php',
        templateUrl: 'partials/exemplo.html',
        controller: 'lista'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
}]);
//roda a app
app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);
```

Melhor que isso impossível!

Answer (score 1):

Sei que já tem várias respostas aqui, mas gostaria de soluncionar seu problema baseado apenas nos dados que você dera. Primeiro, vamos começar onde começaste, no `con-bd.php`:

```
<?php
...

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $base) or die(mysqli_error());

$query = "SELECT matricula, nome FROM sca_pessoa" or die(mysqli_error());

$result = $conn->query($query);

//Declare uma array para colecionar todos os $rows
$end_result = array();

/*
   Aqui, em vez de usar mysqli_fetch_array(), que devolve ambos
    arrays associativas e arrays numericais, usa mysqli_fetch_assoc -
    assim, consegue pegar uma array associativa assim:
    ['matricula'=>'182354X', 'nome'=>'RAFAEL CAMPOS PIMENTEL']
*/
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //adicione essa array associativa à array normal
    $end_result[] = $row;
}

//specifique-se que o conteúdo é do JSON - AngularJS vai gostar disso :D
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//Por fim, transforme o array em JSON e termina a execução.
echo json_encode($end_result);
die();
?>
```

Depois, no seu `app.js`, precisa definir o serviço que faz essa chamada ao `con-bd.php`. Um exemplo simples <sup><sub>(*baseado numa [outra resposta dessa mesma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58795/4171)*)</sub></sup>:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.factory('services', ['$http', function($http) {
    var obj={};
    obj.getPessoas = function() { return $http.get('con-bd.php'); }
    return obj;
}]);

app.controller("pessoasCtrl", function($scope, services) {
    services.getPessoas().then( function(data) {
        $scope.pessoas = data.data;
    } );
});

app.run();
```

E ao final, no seu `Index.html`, precisaria de algo assim (bem aparecido com o original, simplesmente adicionando os bindings):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App com PHP e AngularJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="pessoasCtrl">
        <h3>App PHP + AngularJS</h3>
        <div ng-repeat="pessoa in pessoas">
            <b>Matricula:</b> {{pessoa.matricula}} <br/>
            <b>Nome:</b> {{pessoa.nome}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Usando exatamente esses códigos, consegui colocar os dados apropriados no site. Claro que estava sem CSS nenhuma, mas deu para mostrar as coisas. O detalhe maior é o jeito em que estava lendo o banco de dados. Se não especificar `MYSQLI_ASSOC` quando usa `mysqli_fetch_array()`, vai devolver **ambas** associativa e numeral - que traduz diretamente ao JSON estranho que você estava vendo.

Um outro detalhe também, é que é preciso lembrar que uma array no PHP nem sempre traduz para uma array no JSON - a regra é o seguinte:

```
PHP                  JSON
-----------------    -------
array associativa    objeto
array numeral        array
```

Ou seja:

```
['nome'=>'joao']       --> {nome:'joao'}
[0=>'nome']            --> ['nome']
[0=>['nome'=>'joao']]  --> [{nome:'joao'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
$result = array();
while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
    $result[] = $row;
}
json_encode($data);
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema, tem que ver a chamada do seu server tbm:

```
return $http.get(serviceBase + 'customers');
```